# Excluding pages from forms auth - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I understand there are 2 ways of excluding pages from forms auth. Either by using another web.config file in the folder that has pages that need to be excluded or by using the location element

```
<location path="ExcludePage1.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

I have 20 pages scattered all around the web app, so I cannot create a separate web.config. However, due to the number of pages that need to be excluded, I would rather not want to add the location section for each of these pages.

Is there another option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately no.  You can only specify one path per location element.

This is mainly due to the complexity of .config file inheritance (multiple possible web.configs and machine.config).