# How to apply form authentication for some web pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, web-config, form-authentication

Please consider this scenario:

I have a project that it contains some web pages.I add form authentication based on `Active Direcotry` for my all web pages.For Example :

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://testdomain.test.com/CN=Users,DC=testdomain,DC=test,DC=com" />
</connectionStrings>
<authorization>
     <deny users="?" />      
</authorization>
```

Now I want to exclude some pages from form authentication.How I can exclude some pages in `web.config`?

thanks

Comment: In this post you can find your response:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354185/how-do-i-grant-anonymous-access-to-a-url-using-formsauthentication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your page in a separate directory and modify the web.config accordingly.and You  can do this also

```
    <configuration>
       <location path="CreateAccount.aspx">
        <system.web>
         <authorization>
          <allow users="?"/>
         <authorization>
        </system.web>
      </location>  
   </configuration>
```

More discussions

[link1](http://forums.asp.net/t/1199910.aspx/1)

[Excluding pages from forms auth - ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178713/excluding-pages-from-forms-auth-asp-net)

Comment: I had to put. <allow users="*" />

Answer (score 3):

One easy way of doing it is to make a separate folder within your application for public pages. In that folder you place all the pages that you want to be excluded from authentication. Then you place a web.config within that folder with only the authentication settings, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```